# How to observe the width change of element with jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, observers, mutation-observers

While researching about above mention questions, I came up with solution which did not work in my case.

[MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) and [Resize Observer](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/resizeobserver)

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    $parent.find('.ListSliderWrapper').removeClass('binded');
    let carousel = new CarouselInit($parent.find('.ListSliderWrapper'));
});
observer.observe($parent.find('.ListSliderWrapper')[0], {
    attributes: true,
    attributeFilter: ['class']
});
```

The above mention code went into infinite loop.

```
function observeSize() {
    $parent.find('.ListSliderWrapper').removeClass('binded');
    let carousel = new CarouselInit($parent.find('.ListSliderWrapper'));
}

new ResizeObserver(observeSize).observe($('.ListSliderWrapper')[0])
```

This code works only on google chrome.

**I am searching the way to track the width change of an element by class with cross browser compatibility.**

Comment: In the first snippet you must check if the class is present first and remove it only then. The only cross-browser fallback would be periodic checking in setInterval.

Comment: In first snippet, both class `.ListSliderWrapper` and `.binded` are there. Problem is that MutationObserver will track the change in class, here in this element I need to add new class and remove it frequently base on user interaction on that element.

Comment: Uhm, I probably suck at explaining but it's really obvious, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50916724).